# How does whatsapp receive multiple notification when APNS stores only one in when device is offline?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

According to the official Apple documentation, APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) stores only the last notification if the device is offline.

Apple Push Notification Service includes a default Quality of Service (QoS) component that performs a store-and-forward function. If APNs attempts to deliver a notification but the device is offline, the QoS stores the notification. It retains only one notification per application on a device: the last notification received from a provider for that application. When the offline device later reconnects, the QoS forwards the stored notification to the device. The QoS retains a notification for a limited period before deleting it.

Then how do apps like whatsapp send messages from multiple users when the device comes online? Those messages would have been received as separate notification if device was online.

Comment: "when the device comes online":  I suspect this: the app probably sends a "Hello" notification (likely via HTTP) to the server when it comes to the foreground. The server then composes the various notifications based on its persisted data and sends them to the APNs. Since the device is now in foreground the notifications have a "good chance" to be delivered.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected and [documented](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns) behaviour

> As a best-effort service, APNs may reorder notifications you send to the same device token. If APNs can’t deliver a notification immediately, it may store the notification for 30 days or less, depending on the date you specify in the apns-expiration header. APNs attempts to deliver the notification the next time the device activates and is available online.

> APNs stores only one notification per bundle ID. When you send multiple notifications to the same device for a bundle ID, APNs selects only one notification to store in a non-deterministic way.

You should not rely on APNs to deliver information to your app. It should always check with your server for new or updated information.